# Not able to activate a variable assigned sheet in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am developing a macro which would loop through sheets in the folder and get values from the sheets to a master file.

```
Set wkbInpt = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & "\" & Myfile)
```

The opened sheet is set to the variable and I am trying to get the value from sheet1 not the name of the sheet but by using

```
Inp_Data = wkbInpt.Sheet1.Range("C5").Value
```

But when I run this I get the error that Object doesn't support property or method.

Comment: You have to use the sheet name or index in such cases.

Comment: You can only use a codename like `Sheet1` in the same workbook as the code (unless you've set a reference between projects). You should probably be using the tab name as `wkbInpt.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C5").Value`

Comment: Tab name is different for each sheet and hence that would not work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56762472/how-can-i-get-a-worksheet-object-from-a-specific-workbook-not-thisworkbook-u/56762564#56762564